# Harmonic numbers probability similar to coupon collector

Tags: probability

We're ordering beer with uniform probability and with replacement. I calculated the expected value of receiving $n$ different brands of beer from some company is $E(X) = n\cdot H_n$. I've defined a random variable as:

$X = $ total number of distinct brand received.

With every brand we receive, it slightly decreases our chance of receiving an unique brand of beer.

If someone places $m$ amount of orders for beer, the what is the expected value? *What is the number of distinct amounts of brands of beer will we receive if we only order m amounts where there exists n amount of brands*

I'm puzzled on how to compose a general equation to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is less than clear, but I suppose you have $n$ distinct and equally probably brands and you take a sample of size $m$ with replacement, receiving $X$ distinct brands.

You can work out the probablity of not getting a particular brand as $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^m$ and so the expected number of distinct brands received is $$E[X]=n\left(1- \left(1-\frac1n\right)^m\right)$$ which for large $n$ is close to $n \left(1- e^{-m/n}\right)$.

Comment: Henry, why is it that you take $1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^m$? Is it because  $1-\frac{1}{n}$ is the probability of not getting a particular brand, so we need to take the complement of that to result in the probability of receiving a particular brand? 

If so, isn't kind of convoluted? Can we use $(\frac{1}{n})^m$ for the the chance to receive a particular brand and hence $E(X) = n(\frac{1}{n})^m$? Maybe I'm wrong, but I would really like to know why we need to work out the probability of NOT getting a particular brand...

Comment: $(\frac{1}{n})^m$ is the probability of getting a particular brand all $m$ times. $1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^m$ is the probability of getting a particular brand at least once.

Comment: Could you explain $(1-\frac{1}{n})^m)$ and exactly why we want to count the probability of not getting a particular brand? Also WHY would be take the complement of that to result in getting a particular brand at least once? I don't understand your train of thought. Describe please? thanks.

Comment: Try an example such as $m=2$ and $n=3$ and work out the probability of not getting brand A, the probability of getting Brand A at least once, and the expected number of brands you get in total.